# Break function execution from interrupt

Tags: stm32

I write firmware for stm32. There is function a() executes in main loop. I need to break execution of this function if happens uart interrupt! Is it possible? Thanks)

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can do that. The canonical method is to create a `volatile` *flag* variable accessible within the scope of both the IRQ and your `a()` method. Initialise it to `false`.

When your IRQ method wants to tell your `a()` method to do something then it sets the flag to true. In your `a()` method you frequently poll the flag and if it's true then you act upon it.

The fact that you're asking this makes me think that perhaps you're making a blocking call somewhere in `a()` and you want it to be somehow forcibly unblocked by the interrupt code. That's not possible. If your code is like this then you'll need to redesign it to be non-blocking.